# Error opening a .fxml document in Scene Builder (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm creating a login app in JavaFX. I received this error while opening the scenebuilder: "Could not open Loggin.fxml. Open operation has failed. Make sure that the chosen file is a valid fxml document."

Clicking on "Show details", it shown me this error:

```
java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 7; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.glue.GlueLoader.load(GlueLoader.java:93)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.glue.GlueLoader.load(GlueLoader.java:76)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.glue.GlueDocument.<init>(GlueDocument.java:54)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:74)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:95)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2370)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:655)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:386)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:579)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleOpenFilesAction(SceneBuilderApp.java:447)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleLaunch(SceneBuilderApp.java:427)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStartGeneric(AppPlatform.java:139)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStart(AppPlatform.java:106)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.start(SceneBuilderApp.java:371)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 7; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPIData(XMLScanner.java:723)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanPIData(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1018)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPI(XMLScanner.java:691)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:912)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.glue.GlueLoader.load(GlueLoader.java:91)
        ... 24 more
```

This is the fxml resource:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<TitledPane animated="false" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" text="WELCOME TO PAY-APP" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Login">
  <content>
    <AnchorPane fx:id="arch" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="lblog" layoutX="43.0" layoutY="43.0" text="LOG IN " textAlignment="CENTER" />
            <TextField fx:id="user" layoutX="103.0" layoutY="74.0" />
            <PasswordField fx:id="paswd" layoutX="103.0" layoutY="131.0" />
            <Button fx:id="logbt" layoutX="152.0" layoutY="197.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#log" text="LOG IN" />
            <Label layoutX="26.0" layoutY="78.0" text="USERNAME:" />
            <Label layoutX="25.0" layoutY="135.0" text="PASSWORD:" />
            <Button fx:id="sgnbt" layoutX="377.0" layoutY="280.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="SIGN UP!" />
            <Label fx:id="lbmem" layoutX="285.0" layoutY="43.0" text="NOT A MEMBER? SIGN UP!" />
            <Label layoutX="288.0" layoutY="78.0" text="NAME:" />
            <Label layoutX="288.0" layoutY="111.0" text="LAST NAME:" />
            <Label layoutX="288.0" layoutY="148.0" text="USERNAME:" />
            <Label layoutX="287.0" layoutY="189.0" text="PASSWORD:" />
            <Label layoutX="287.0" layoutY="231.0" text="PASSWORD AGAIN:" />
            <TextField fx:id="name" layoutX="399.0" layoutY="66.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="usersg" layoutX="399.0" layoutY="144.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="lname" layoutX="399.0" layoutY="107.0" />
            <PasswordField fx:id="paswdsg" layoutX="399.0" layoutY="185.0" />
            <PasswordField fx:id="pswdsga" layoutX="399.0" layoutY="227.0" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
  </content>
</TitledPane>
```

The thing is I worked with this document before and it was compiling without problems and errors. Now I just want to add a new button to my app and it seems I can't open it... Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: You're missing a `<` at the start of the file.